# Активный подпункт меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<li><a href="#">Главная</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Разработка сайтов</a>
</li>
<li class="submenu"><a href="#">Услуги</a> 
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Наши работы</a>
</li>
```

нажав на услуги (становится активным как и остальные меню, фон зеленый), список открывается, нажимаем на 1 - перехолим на страницу 1- пункт услуги активный все также, 1-черным цветом, а 2 и 3 серым

```js
$(".submenu").click(function(){
  $(".submenu ul").slideToggle();
  $(".submenu").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.left-menu {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  min-height: 750px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
ul.menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
ul.menu li {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

ul.menu li:hover a,
ul.menu li.submenu:hover,
ul.menu li.submenu ul li:hover,
.active {
  background-color: #02A511;
  color: white;
}

ul.menu li.submenu ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.menu li ul, ul.menu li.submenu ul li{
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  color: black;
}
ul.menu li.submenu ul li{
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu" id="gmenu">
  <ul class="menu" id="fixed">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Разработка сайтов</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Услуги</a>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Наши работы</a></li>
    <li><a>Акции</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a>Хостинг</a></li>
    <li><a>Услуги копирайта</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a>О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы хотите делать пункты меню активными на js? У вас странички не генерируются с помощью php?

Comment: я работаю в modx

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: вот такое хочу сделать меню http://yanov.by/

Comment: Вообще непонятно, 1) что вы хотите получить и 2) с какими трудностями столкнулись, в чём помощь-то нужна.

Comment: такое же меню и такие же активные пункты меню, только в моем коде

Comment: Wayfinder погуглите - миллиард примеров, похожий на ваш нашел на 4 стр поиска... банальная верстка шаблона выдачи результатов работы плагина, есть же все в комплекте плагина! Установите плагин из репозитория и в шаблоне вставьте [[Wayfinder? &startId=`0`]] - начните с этого!